# Atualizar a versão do R do RStudio?

Tags: r

A versão do R que tenho instalada  está desatualizada. Qual o procedimento para atualizar o R considerando que utilizo o RStudio no Windows?

Comment: Da uma lida nessa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13656802/3517631

Comment: Obrigado @Ricardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atualizar a versão do R pra quem utiliza no **Windows** é muito simples, conforme dito acima. Não sei se você está pensando em atualizar ou reinstalar, mas pode verificar esse [tutorial](http://talkitbr.com/2015/10/27/instalando-r-no-windows/) com todas as dicas.
O RStudio também disponibiliza uma versão desktop gratuita em seu [site](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/#Desk).

Answer (score 3):

Existem várias maneiras, uma delas é utilizando o pacote `installr` e aplicando a função `updateR()`:

```
library (installr)
updateR()
```

maiores informações podem ser encontrar neste [tutorial](https://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/).

Comment: Links não são considerados como resposta (podem ser removidos/alterados).

Comment: Entendido, acabei de alterar.

Comment: Jean, como você mesmo disse, existem várias maneiras. Seria legal citar também como atualizar manualmente e verificar a versão e configurar, se necessário, no RStudio. E também citar que o `installr` só funciona no Windows, em outros OS é necessário instalar "normalmente".

Comment: @Molx.... Opa, assim que puder farei as devidas considerações, mas até lá deixarei a pergunta em aberto caso alguém se habilite.